# make-distribution.sh failed on Make R package step failed. Did not provide parm

Tags: r, apache-spark

Ran this line of code:  ./dev/make-distribution.sh --name appx-spark-320 --pip --r --tgz -Pkubernetes and near the end of the script received this error message:

Cannot find 'R_HOME'. Please specify 'R_HOME' or make sure R is properly installed.  Thing is, I didn't want R installed (see code line above) and don't think I did anything for this test to fail (line 244 in make-distribution.sh) "if [ "$MAKE_R" == "true" ]; then"  Running spark 3-2-0 build from source using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the parameter --r is used when you want to include "R" in your distribution.  Go figure. :-)  How about --R guys?